# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSMS' of null

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, cordova-plugins

Below code is a cordova android sms acess permission plugin code. and it is working fine.

inside that i am trying to call my `this.getSMS()` function it is throughing error

```
setTimeout(() => {
      this.holders.dissmissLoadingCustom();
      platform.ready().then(() => { 

      var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;

        permissions.hasPermission(permissions.READ_SMS, checkPermissionCallback, null);

        function checkPermissionCallback(status) {
          if(!status.hasPermission) {
            var errorCallback = () => {
              console.log("invoking the errorCallback");
              alert('READ_SMS permission is not turned on');
            }

            permissions.requestPermission(
              permissions.READ_SMS,
              (status) => {
                console.log("invoking status");

              if(!status.hasPermission) {
                console.log("invoke !status.hasPermission");
                errorCallback();
              }
              else{
                console.log("invoking else part !status.hasPermission");
                this.getSMS();//this line through error
              }
            },
            errorCallback);
          }
        }

      });

    }, 10000);
```

> if the user tap allow then i am trying to call my `this.getSMS()` as you can see in the above code.
>   if user deny then i am just getting error callback.

i dont know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: This might help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: make `checkPermissionCallback` an arrow function

Comment: @Prajwal i am trying to do as below answer but i am not able to slove the issue if you have any idea please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `checkPermissionCallback` as a regular function. The `this` keyword points to that function and not the actual class in which it is defined.

```
setTimeout(() => {
      this.holders.dissmissLoadingCustom();
      platform.ready().then(() => { 

      var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;

        permissions.hasPermission(permissions.READ_SMS, (status)=>checkPermissionCallback(status), null);//use arrow to call

        function checkPermissionCallback(status) {
          if(!status.hasPermission) {
            var errorCallback = () => {
              console.log("invoking the errorCallback");
              alert('READ_SMS permission is not turned on');
            }

            permissions.requestPermission(
              permissions.READ_SMS,
              (status) => {
                console.log("invoking status");

              if(!status.hasPermission) {
                console.log("invoke !status.hasPermission");
                errorCallback();
              }
              else{
                console.log("invoking else part !status.hasPermission");
                this.getSMS();//this line through error
              }
            },
            errorCallback);
          }
        }

      });

    }, 10000);
```

Or you can save `this` to another variable before the function definition or use `bind`.

Comment: after trying the updated one i am not invoking the setTimeout itself any idea

Comment: use the other way then set `self=this` before the function definition

Comment: on trying with your code `permissions.hasPermission(permissions.READ_SMS, checkPermissionCallback, null); ` this piece of line is not exicuting

Comment: using `self` or arrow?

Comment: using arrow i am not able to invoke self i have not tried yet

Comment: wait have a different idea.try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134572/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-suraj).